# Unity LoadScene broke the object script behave

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am self-learning unity, right now i am trying to make a reset button when the player die,
you can see the player, enemy, and bullet are moving normally, in my GIF in the link below, then when the player die, you can press the button to reload the scene by using :`SceneManager.LoadScene(indexNumber);`
but when i press the button, the scene is reloaded, but all the GameManager and Object are not working properly: player can not move, enemy doesnt move, gameManager doesnt spawn enemies, bullet doesnt move nor Destroy

this is GameManager script:

```
{
    public Transform playerPos;
    public EnemyControl enemy;
    public PlayerControl thePlayer;
    public PlayerHealth health;
    public GameObject canvas;

    public float TimeToBegin;
    public float Rate;
    public float radius;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControl>();
        canvas.SetActive(false);
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", TimeToBegin, Rate);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void Spawn()
    {
        Vector3 randomPos = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerPos.position);
        randomPos += transform.position;
        

        Vector3 direction = randomPos - transform.position;
        direction.Normalize();

        float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, direction);
        float dotProductAngle = Mathf.Acos(dotProduct / transform.forward.magnitude * direction.magnitude);

        randomPos.x = Mathf.Cos(dotProductAngle) * radius + playerPos.position.x;
        randomPos.y = 1f;
        randomPos.z = Mathf.Sin(dotProductAngle * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 1f : -1f)) * radius + playerPos.position.z;

        EnemyControl newEnemy = Instantiate(enemy, randomPos, rotation);
        newEnemy.transform.position = randomPos;

        
    }
    public void GameOver()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        canvas.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void Replay()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

This is PlayerHealth script(trigger Replay() method when player health < 0):

```
{
    public int Health;
    public int currentHealth;

    public float flashLength;
    private float flashCountdown;
   
    public GameManager manager;
    //make player change color when taking hit
    private Renderer rend;
    private Color storeColor;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = Health;
        //get current object color material
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        storeColor = rend.material.GetColor("_Color");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            manager.GameOver();
        }
        if(flashCountdown > 0)
        {
            flashCountdown-= Time.deltaTime;
            if(flashCountdown <= 0)
            {
                rend.material.SetColor("_Color", storeColor);
            }
        }
    }
    public void hurtPlayer(int damagetaken)
    {
        currentHealth -= damagetaken;
        flashCountdown = flashLength;
        //change current object color material to white material
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue); 
    }
}
```

Player control script:

```
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private Vector3 moveInput;
    private Vector3 moveVelocity;

    private Camera pcam;
    public GunControl theGun;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pcam = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        //get position of mouse
        moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput * moveSpeed;

        //create a invinsible ray from camera to mouse position
        Ray cameraRay = pcam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        float rayLength;

        //draw a line(blue) to debug camera look position
        if(groundPlane.Raycast(cameraRay,out rayLength))
        {
            Vector3 pointToLook = cameraRay.GetPoint(rayLength);
            Debug.DrawLine(cameraRay.origin, pointToLook,Color.blue);

            transform.LookAt(new Vector3(pointToLook.x,transform.position.y,pointToLook.z));
        }

        //command shoot bullet when click left mouse(0)
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            theGun.isFiring = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            theGun.isFiring = false;
        }
    }

     void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = moveVelocity;
    }
}
```

Enemy control Script:

```
{
    private Rigidbody enemyrb;
    public float moveSpeed;

    public PlayerControl thePlayer;

    private Animation anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyrb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControl>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        enemyrb.velocity = (transform.forward * moveSpeed);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //face to player position (but not using y axis)
        transform.LookAt(new Vector3(thePlayer.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, thePlayer.transform.position.z));

        if(thePlayer.transform.position == null)
        {
            anim.Play("Dance");
        }

        //face to player position (all axis)
        //transform.LookAt(thePlayer.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Gun control script:

```
public class GunControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isFiring;

    public BullletControl bullet;
    public float bulletSpeed;

    public float timeBetweenShots;
    private float shotCounter;

    public Transform firePoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isFiring)
        {
            if (shotCounter > 0)
            {
                shotCounter = -Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (shotCounter <= 0)
            {
                shotCounter = timeBetweenShots * Time.deltaTime;
                BullletControl newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as BullletControl;
                newBullet.speed = bulletSpeed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            shotCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Bullet script:

```
{
    public float speed;

    public float lifeTime;
    public int damagedealt;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(lifeTime <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
         if(other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealthManager>().HurtEnemy(damagedealt);
            Destroy(gameObject);
         }  
    }
}
```

how can i reload the scene correctly without break the entire scene ?

Comment: You are going to have to make your question more detailed. We're unlikely to download a random Unity project from a Google Drive. So try to include the necessary information in the question without us having to download things.

Comment: no this is my video of showing the problem not downloading the whole code, i  have edit the question, please check again

Comment: People want to read and search for issues. Not watch videos. We need the code we need to know how you built it. As id guess you did some form of don’t destroy but didn’t account for when a new scene comes you may have to find some new elements

Comment: It totally depends upon how you are implementing things so without looking at your game manager class I don't think anyone could help you sir, so if you can upload game manager class that would be helpfull to know and resolve your issue.

Comment: i am edited my question please check again